# $k$-Lipshitz function $f: (E,d_E) \to (F,d_F)$ prove if $f$ is k-Lipshitz then $f$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$k$-Lipshitz function $f: (E,d_E) \to (F,d_F)$ prove if $f$ is k-Lipshitz then $f$ is continuous where $ (E,d_E), (F,d_F)$ are metric spaces

$f$ is said to be $k$-Lipshitz if for $f : E \to F$ for $k \ge 0$ when $\forall x,y \in E$ we have $d_F(f(x),f(y)) \le kd_E(x,y)$

Suppose $f$ is in fact $k$-Lipshitz then let $x, y \in E$ and $k \ge 0$ we get

$d_F(f(x),f(y)) \le kd_E(x,y)$

case i) $k = 0$ then the RHS is $0$ so we know the LHS to be $0$ by assumption so $f(x) = f(y)$ then$ \forall z \in E$ define $\displaystyle \delta = d(x,y) + d(x,z) + \frac{1}{d(x,y)} > d(x,y)$ (possible by metric space definition, triangle inequality),  and let $\epsilon = \delta  $ then $d(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$ as the LHS is always $0$

case ii) $k > 0$ this seems that it would be written up similarly since be $k$-Lipshitz is either keeping the mapped distance equal or less so $\epsilon = \delta$ seems fine but I could use some advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overthinking this.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. If $d_E(x,y)<\frac\varepsilon K$, then
$$d_F(f(x),f(y))\leqslant K d_E(x,y) < K\left(\frac\varepsilon K\right)=\varepsilon, $$
so $f$ is continuous.